# Como verificar se a entrada do usuário é um número negativo e exibir uma mensagem de erro?

Tags: c

O enunciado diz:

> Escreva um programa que leia vários números inteiros e positivos e que calcule e mostre o maior e o menor número lido. Considere que:
>   Para encerrar a entrada de dados, deve ser digitado zero.
>   Para valores negativos, deve ser enviada uma mensagem, informando que o valor é negativo.
>   Os valores negativos ou iguais a zero não entrarão nos cálculos.

Até o momento fiz da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)



{


    int quant_val=0,numero=1,soma=0,maior=0,menor=0;

    printf("Insira o numero positivo: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);

    while(numero>=1 || numero!=0){

        quant_val++;
        soma=soma+numero;



        if(numero<0){
            printf("Valor e negativo!\n");
        }

        if(numero==1){
            maior=numero;
            menor=numero;
        }

        if(numero>maior){
            maior=numero;
        }

        if(numero<menor){
            maior=numero;
        }


    printf("Insira o numero positivo: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);

    }


    printf("O numero maior e: %d\n",maior);
    printf("O numero menor e: %d\n",menor);
    printf("A soma dos numeros e: %d\n",soma);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

O problema é que não estou conseguindo remover os número negativos do cálculo.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: E o que acontece quando você insere um número negativo?

Comment: Resolvido na explicação do caro @Rovann Linhalis. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é apenas lógica.
Para ser encerrada a leitura, deve ser digitado o `0` logo o while está errado:

O correto seria:

```
 while(numero!=0)
```

E, número negativos ou 0, não devem entrar no calculo, e deve exibir uma mensagem para valores negativos:

```
    if(numero<0){
        printf("Valor e negativo!\n");
    }
    else //Aqui está faltando!
    {

        quant_val++;
        soma=soma+numero; 

        if(numero>maior){
            maior=numero;
        }

        if(numero<menor){
            menor=numero;
        }

    }
```

A primeira atribuição de maior, e menor valor, faça na primeira leitura apenas, e não dentro do `while`:

```
int quant_val=0,numero=1,soma=0,maior=0,menor=0;

printf("Insira o numero positivo: ");
scanf("%d",&numero);

maior = numero;
menor = numero;

while(numero != 0)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Opa, bem isso mesmo. Estava quebrando a cabeça com isso, muito obrigado!